# Qual é a diferença entre Error e Exception?

Tags: java, exceção

Por que temos Exceptions (`IOException`, por exemplo) e Errors (`OutOfMemoryError`, por exemplo)?

Sei que ambos herdam da classe [`Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html), mas qual é a diferença entre eles?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/912352/5524514

Comment: Resposta do Vinny Godoy =: http://www.guj.com.br/t/qual-verdadeira-diferenca-de-error-e-exception/74549/8

Comment: @diegofm valeu. Vou responder aqui com base nessa resposta

Comment: O arquivo não está lá !!.... o arquivo está lá , eu li e cheguei no último registro dele , não tem próximo é uma exceção neste caso ... mas veja as duas boas respostas que foram dadas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baseado [nessa resposta do SO gringo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912334/differences-between-exception-and-error/912352#912352):

`Error`s são problemas muito grandes que não devem ser tratados ou lançados.

São problemas que quando acontecem, não tem muito o que fazer.

Já `Exception`s podem ser tratadas e lançadas. Podem representar problemas grandes, mas nada comparado aos problemas do tipo `Error`.